# How to load local html file in Flutter using webview_flutter: ^4.2.2

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

**Objective:**
I am trying to load local `.html` page placed inside assets and using WebviewWidget but could not loading in iOS and Android.

**Issue:**
Not loading local html file.

Dependencies `webview_flutter: ^4.2.2`

Assets defined inside `pubspec.yaml` file

```
  assets:
    - assets/test/
```

I have `index.html` inside my assets folder as like below

[image]

Code in `main.dart`

```
class WebviewLocalState extends State<WebviewLocal> {
  //
  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _webViewController = WebViewController()
      ..loadFlutterAsset('assets/test/index.html');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: _webViewController),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?